# How to remove the value of the third column, from the fourth column, if it exists, in a csv file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Ubuntu 16.04
Bash 4.3.48

I am wanting to remove the value of column 3 from column 4 if it exists including space after the value.

```
Before: "Acura","CL","2.2","2.2 2dr Coupe","FWD","Automatic","Gasoline"
After:  "Acura","CL","2.2","2dr Coupe","FWD","Automatic","Gasoline"

Before: "Acura","CL","2.2 Premium","2.2 Premium 2dr Coupe","FWD","Manual","Gasoline"
After:  "Acura","CL","2.2 Premium","2dr Coupe","FWD","Manual","Gasoline"
```

I tried using awk as suggested:

```
root@0000 ~ # awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub($3,"",$4)} 1' data-one-makes-models.csv > temp; head -n5 temp
"make","model","trim","style","drivetrain","transmission","fueltype"
"Acura","CL","2.2","2.2 2dr Coupe","FWD","Automatic","Gasoline"
"Acura","CL","2.2","2.2 2dr Coupe","FWD","Manual","Gasoline"
"Acura","CL","2.2 Premium","2.2 Premium 2dr Coupe","FWD","Automatic","Gasoline"
"Acura","CL","2.2 Premium","2.2 Premium 2dr Coupe","FWD","Manual","Gasoline"
```

Am I redirecting the output correctly or should I restructure the command?

Comment: It is always recommended to post your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem with you post, so kindly do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following(written and tested with shown samples only).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {val=$3;gsub(/\"/,"",val);sub(val,"",$4);sub(/^" /,"\"",$4)} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: @CuriousSam,please check my edit now and let me know then?

Comment: @CuriousSam, hey BTW, my name is Ravinder Singh :)

Comment: My apologies Ravinder. Your edited version seemed to do the trick. Hat off to you mate.

Comment: @CuriousSam, hey,no need to apologies I was pulling your leg :) :) Request you to always put your efforts in your post, on SO we encourage all to do so, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: I normally do but I was pretty stuff with this one. Appreciate the guidance as always mate.

Comment: That would change `"2.2","Big 12324 Coupe"` into `"2.2","Big 14 Coupe"`. It'd also fail if any field before the 5th contained a comma.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you're using `,` as the separator but your fields are actually separated by `","` so just change your FS and OFS settings to match your data:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""} {sub($3,"",$4)} 1' file
"Acura","CL","2.2"," 2dr Coupe","FWD","Automatic","Gasoline"
"Acura","CL","2.2 Premium"," 2dr Coupe","FWD","Manual","Gasoline"
```

and to get rid of the space left at the start of $4 include spaces in the regexp:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""} {sub($3" *","",$4)} 1' file
"Acura","CL","2.2","2dr Coupe","FWD","Automatic","Gasoline"
"Acura","CL","2.2 Premium","2dr Coupe","FWD","Manual","Gasoline"
```

It's not robust though due to the use of $3 as a regexp and so RE metachars like `.` will be treated as such:

```
$ echo '"Acura","CL","2.2","Big 12324 Coupe","FWD","Automatic","Gasoline"' |
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""} {sub($3,"",$4)} 1'
"Acura","CL","2.2","Big 14 Coupe","FWD","Automatic","Gasoline"
```

For this to work robustly you should really be doing string rather than regexp operations:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""} s=index($4,$3){$4=substr($4,1,s-1) substr($4,s+length($3)); gsub(/ +/," ",$4); gsub(/^ | $/,"",$4)} 1' file
"Acura","CL","2.2","2dr Coupe","FWD","Automatic","Gasoline"
"Acura","CL","2.2 Premium","2dr Coupe","FWD","Manual","Gasoline"
```

and if you only want to remove $3 if it occurs at the beginning of $4 then just change `s=index($4,$3)` to `(s=index($4,$3))==1`.